# Why are my imports failing when running from command line while imports succeed if running from PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-import, python-3.7

I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "

A little background:

1) My venv is using python 3.6.9

2) Already tried adding the folders to PYTHONPATH via sys.path.append

3) Heirarchy, or the relevant part:

/**project folder**

|--folder A

```
  |--__init__.py
  |--a.py
```

|--folder B

```
  |--__init__.py
  |--b.py
```

|--**init**.py

I am trying to import from a.py to b.py
Tried it in various ways-

1) import b

2) from b import x

Would really appreciate some help, been on this for some time now.

Comment: you should specify folder B when you want to import b when you want to run it by command line. if you open it from pycharm as project it will find your import because folder B and A is in the same project.

Comment: I do specify it in the import - "from b import <some module>.method. Is this what you meant?

Comment: no, for example if your main project name is AB that contains folder A and B, you should import like "from AB.B.b import <some module>"

Comment: I tried intering "from AB..." 
import B
PyCharm marks it with red as an error

Comment: Add PYTHONPATH by console (eg. linux ```export PYTHONPATH=your_path_to_project```). Just do it before you run your py script

Comment: @CezarySzulc Thanks for the suggestion, but this did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Why?`

Because you run your script differently. When you run it with PyCharm then PyCharm adds project directory and all the sourse directories to `sys.path`. That's why `import A.a` works. However when you run your script with console command then only file location is added to `sys.path`. Just print `sys.path` to see what it contains.

To solve the issue you may use various approaches.

Easiest way is to use `PYTHONPATH`. For example, on Windows you can run command `set PYTHONPATH=[project_folder];%PYTHONPATH%` then `import A.a` works. Or you can run slightly different version `set PYTHONPATH=[project_folder/A];%PYTHONPATH%` then `import a` works. Basically this command adds directory to `sys.path`.

Alternative solution is to have `main` function in `b.py` and some `launching_script.py` in `project_folder`. Instead of running `b.py` you run your `launching_script.py`. Thus you always have project directory in `sys.path`. So absolute imports starting with project directory (like `import A.a`) will work in both PyCharm and console.

Another approach is some ugly code like the following one:

```
try:
    import A.a as module_a
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import pathlib
    import sys
    sys.path.append(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent))
    import A.a as module_a
```

Also you may use relative imports. A little harder, less readable and error-prone way demanding some work on the project structure.

Comment: Thanks for the imput.
Although- I have already tried sertting the PYTHONPATH via sys.path or hardcoding it with export PYTHONPATH=... (linux), I have tried relative imports, and what not. I have no idea why this is happening.
None of these work.
My main is within the file I am importing to.

Comment: OK... only thing that worked is your "ugly code" suggestion...
Thanks  for that!!

Comment: @TomerInbar I tried all 3 approaches (except relative imports) - all work for my dummy test project (py3.7, win10). Basically they all are about adding `project_directory` to `sys.path` in a slightly different ways. So all 3 solutions should work. I recommend to examine the problem with `print(sys.path)`. Have a look at the actual content - `project_directory` should be there along with `script_directory`. Wish you luck.